# How to get order no of the azure scaled app service instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an Azure app service (asp.net MVC web app) and I have enabled auto-scaling (max 3 instances). Now I want that when new instances are scaled out I want what is its order no?
For example:
if currently 1 instance is running and then a scale-out happens then that new instance should identify that it is no 2 from the app startup.
Again if a scale-out now happen then that instance should identity it is no 3 from app startup.

How can I do this in C#?
   In start up class ->

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
          // How can I get the order of the newly created instance from here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround. We can create a Azure SQL Database to store the order number and in our web app, we can store it in cache(something like static variable).

More information for your reference:

[Create an Azure SQL database in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal)